# Can we set the fixed size for both plan cache and data cache?

Tags: sql-server, cache, plan-cache, buffer-pool

As far as I know, SQL Server automatically manages the size for the components of buffer pool. I wonder if it is possible to set pre-defined size for both plan cache and data cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can set Minimum & Maximum server memory to control the range of total memory utilization by the Instance, but there is not fine grained control for the constituent parts that make up "server memory"

Comment: Yes.  The SQL Server design philosophy is strongly biased against exposing manual configuration settings.  Here the system uses a Clock Algorithm to automatically manage the sizes of all the internal caches.  See eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slavao/q-and-a-clock-hands-what-are-they-for